# CSS hover property ignored

Tags: css

Can anyone see why this isnt working? For this example the box should turn white when hovered over.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .box {
        width: 250px; 
        height: 250px; 
        display: block;
        background: #000; 
        border: 1px solid white; 
        float: left
    }
    .inner {
        width: 175px; 
        height: 175px; 
        display: block; 
        margin-top: 15%; 
        margin-left: 15%; 
        background: #fff;
        position: relative
    }
    .boxLink {
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        width: 100%; 
        text-align: center; 
        line-height: 175px; 
        font-size: 30px
    }  
    a:link.boxLink {
        color:#000; 
        background: yellow
    }
    a:visited.boxLink {
        color:#000; 
        background: yellow
    }
    a:hover.boxlink {
        color:#fff; 
        background: white
    }
    a:active.boxLink {
        color:#000; 
        background: green
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="inner">
                <a class="boxLink" href="#">about</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It does work. You appear to have done too much reduction for your reduced test case. (You *haven't* even made the usual error of putting the :visited style further down the cascade then the :hover style).

Comment: To clarify (because there is also the *box* element in the code): Only the **link** will get a white background.

Comment: It's working for me (tested on Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X). What browser are you using?

Comment: @Jacob, thanks now I really know I need to go to bed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the class name **before** `:hover`:

```
a.boxLink:link{color:#000; background: yellow}
a.boxLink:visited{color:#000; background: yellow}
a.boxLink:hover {color:#fff; background: white}
a.boxLink:active {color:#000; background: green}
```

While my suggestion is good practice, you actually made a **spelling error** on that `hover` line:

```
 a.boxlink:hover {color:#fff; background: white}
```

CSS is **case-sensitive**, you need to make that `l` uppercase.

Comment: ack@! I am tired. Thanks! Interesting that the other pseduoClasses worked with the wrong format.. only hover was ignored.

Comment: Where does it say that in the specification? Or are you talking about a bug in a specific browser?

Comment: @David Dorward you're right [CSS2.1 Selectors syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax) says "A simple selector is either a type selector or universal selector followed immediately by zero or more attribute selectors, ID selectors, or pseudo-classes, **in any order**."